# The schema version of 'DuoCode' is incompatible with version 2.0.30625.9003 of NuGet. Convert C# View Model to Java Script View Model

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, knockout.js, duocode

I have installed the DuoCode extension form the following URL and Visual Studio version is 2012.

http://duoco.de/download

When I open any of the sample project Visual studio is throwing the following error:

> The schema version of 'DuoCode' is incompatible with version 2.0.30625.9003 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.

It is the same error I am getting when I try to add the DuoCode compiler by NuGet package via add reference or by package manager console (`Install-Package DuoCode -pre`).

My goal is to migrate Silverlight applications (around 100) to ASP.NET MVC or any javascript framework (Knockout and etc) based application, code as much as less by hand, and use some good tool to convert the Silverlight application as the number of application to migrate is huge.

In this process I came across this DuoCode and felt like it can be used to convert C# viewModel class into javascript/Knockout ViewModel classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your NuGet Package Manager extension in Visual Studio. DuoCode adds the required components (mainly, its compiler) to the project by using NuGet, and that requires NuGet v2.5 and above.

Your NuGet seems to be an old version. Simply update it from the Extensions menu (under Tools), and you're good to go!